# Merge neighbour Lists in List

Tags: list-manipulation, concatenation

I think the following problem is a good exercise. In a `List` of `List`s, merge lists which define neighbour intervals: for example,

```
list = {{1,2},{3.5,4.5},{4.5,10},{10,11},{13,14}}
```

should be "merged" as

```
{{1,2},{3.5,11},{13,14}}
```

It can be assumed that the elements are in the right order (i.e., *not* as in `{{1,2},{3.5,4.5},{13,14},{4.5,10},{10,11}}`. One way of doing it the following:

```
Select[Tally@Flatten@list, #[[2]] == 1 &][[All, 1]] // Partition[#, 2] &
```

It flattens `list` and keep the elements which appear only once, then partition. But I'm sure there are other possibly better solutions. Any ideas?

Comment: `List@@Interval@@list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IntervalUnion`:

```
IntervalUnion @@ (Interval /@ list) /. x_[y__] :> {y}
```

yields:

```
{{1, 2}, {3.5, 11}, {13, 14}}
```